# Thrift TSimpleServer Serve methods fails to wait for connection

Tags: thrift

A very simple thrift based server:

```
 public void RunServer()
    {
        while (_running)
        {
            try
            {

                AutomationMain.Processor processor = new AutomationMain.Processor(this);
                TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(_rxport);


                // _server = new TSimpleServer(processor, serverTransport);
                _server = new TSimpleServer(processor, serverTransport, new TFramedTransport.Factory(), new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());


                Log.Debug("Starting HMI server on port " + _rxport);
                _server.Serve();

            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                Log.Error("Exception in server: ", ee);
            }
        }
        Log.Debug("HMI server stopped");
    }
```

This works fine on my development machine, the call to _server.Serve() blocks waiting for connection, and a client can connect and do its thing.

But installed on another PC on a remote site, the call does not block, it returns immediately and the log file is full of "Starting HMI server on port "  messages.

Any ideas why Serve() does not block and wait?

Comment: Wild guess: The port `_rxport` is in use already by someone/something else? What does ([assuming linux](https://superuser.com/questions/42843/finding-the-process-that-is-using-a-certain-port-in-linux)) `netstat -tulpn | grep <your-port-number-here>` tell?

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed something else had the port!

Added a console to my C#/.NET program so I could see the debug from thrift and it revealed the issue.